# Terminal ~/.profile does not contain `source ~/.bashrc` in OS X 10.9.1

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

Terminal shows below on this stage on gerris installation page: http://gfs.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Mac_OSX_Installation

```
Note: make sure that the file ~/.profile contains the line
source ~/.bashrc
```

But the ~/.profile does not contain source ~/.bashrc. How could I manage it?

```
GNU nano 2.0.6        File: /Users/samirebalta/.profile                     


# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-01-21_at_11:48:31: adding an appropriate $
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


##
# Your previous /Users/samirebalta/.profile file was backed up as /Users/samire$
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-01-21_at_12:00:12: adding an appropriate $
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


##
# Your previous /Users/samirebalta/.profile file was backed up as /Users/samire$
##

                               [ Read 23 lines ]
^G Get Help  ^O WriteOut  ^R Read File ^Y Prev Page ^K Cut Text  ^C Cur Pos
^X Exit      ^J Justify   ^W Where Is  ^V Next Page ^U UnCut Text^T To Spell
```

Comment: If you were attempting to paste the contents of your ~/.profile, note that you only pasted the viewport as per nano, and not the actual file's contents.

Comment: I save it but the problem is                              samires-mbp:~ samirebalta$ nano ~/.bashrc
samires-mbp:~ samirebalta$ nano ~/.profile                          There is no source ~/.bashrc in the ~/.profile

Comment: "Note: make sure that the file ~/.profile contains the line" mess that if .profile does not contain the line then you should add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `source ~/.bashrc` to the end of your `~/.profile` file, save it and restart terminal.

Do you have a `~/.bash_profile` file? Note that if you have both `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` then the `~/.profile` will not be sourced when Terminal.app starts.

Comment: I do not have ~/.bash_profile file.. I am now trying what u all say Thanks very much

Comment: thank you how can I add that line  source ~/.bashrc since even if I type ctrl+X it does not show that line in it then..Thank you

Comment: from terminal, `nano ~/.profile` as you have already done. Scroll to the end of the file and type it in. press ctrl+o and then press enter to save the file, then press ctrl+x to exit nano. Now Restart terminal.